# Text: Validation for semicolon

Tags: validation, syntax, xtext

I have a grammar (similar to JSON) with this instruction:

```
List: 
'{' 
  (fields+=GenericField)* 
 '}';

GenericField:
fieldName=STRING ':' value = GenericTypes (semicolon?=';')? 
;
```

Now I'm writing a custom validator for it to check is semicolon is in each line with an exception for last one, where it is not mandatory.

I tried few ways to accomplish this but I failed. I need suggestion how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, after some late night brainstorming I ended with this:

```
if (!field.semicolon) {
    if ((field.eContainer as Table).fields.indexOf(field) != (field.eContainer as Table).fields.size)
            error('Missing semicolon at end of line.',field,null)
    }
```

it is executed in check methods for Field.
This way I achived my goal and quick fix was just one liner.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the handling of semicolons up to the `List` rule, because it is easier to handle there:

```
List: 
  '{' 
  ( fields+=GenericField (';' fields+=GenericField)*  ';'? )? 
  '}';

GenericField:
  fieldName=STRING ':' value=GenericTypes    
;
```

With this grammar the semicolons are already checked on the syntax level.
So there is no need to write a custom validator for this.

Comment: This works... but. First, it highlights next filedName item when a semicolon is missing. Second, it is hard to write (now, for me) validator to check all lines but last, Last but not least quick fix for this was too much for me. In different solution (see my answer) QF was just one line.

Comment: @KrzysztofDrozd Ah, I see. Position of error-highlight would be misleading to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Either change your grammar to let the parser do checking or provide a check like the following:

```
@Check
def void checkList(List list) {
    for (field : list.fields.take(list.fields.length - 1)) {
        if (!field.semicolon) {
            error("A semicolon is missing", field, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Krzysztof Drozd you can wrap your code in if with instanceof check, xtend will narrow a type for you to Table